# How to create a contract address to automatically send tokens to ETH address

Tags: contract-development, erc-20

How to create a contract  address  to automatically  send tokens to ETH address  and also how can I also be able to get the ETH from the contract  address  to my ETH wallet (I am the contract creator)

I mean for example 
BOB sends 1ETH , BOB will receive 1000Tokens automatically

Also me (owner of the contract)  can get the 1ETH too.

P. S : if it can't be done is their any source code I can be able to use to do it  on a website

Answer (score 1):

Contracts can't detect when tokens are being transferred to them. Contracts can only check a token balance but they have no idea when they have received tokens unless someone tells them so. So you can't make this automatic inside the blockchain. So what you need to do is monitor the token transfers outside the blockchain and when you notice that tokens are being transferred to your contract you can execute a transaction to transfer the tokens onwards.

If a contract has Ether balance you can simply transfer the Ethers to whichever address you want - as long as the contract supports such functionality. So it needs to have a function which is something like this:

```
address payable public myAddress;

function retrieveEthers() public {
    myAddress.transfer(address(this).balance);
}
```

Comment: `Contracts can't detect when tokens are being transferred to them.` This does not apply to all contracts. ERC-223 call tokenFallback function of the recipient if the recipient is contract address.

Comment: Sir hope you see the update I made in the question  I make it more clear if you can answer it

Answer (score 0):

#### General Info

A good starting point would be to learn the basics of Smart Contracts.

- https://ethereum.org/developers/

#### Solidity Banking example

This blog post covers the basics of handling ETH with a solidity smart contract:

- https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/01/05/writing-a-banking-contract/

#### Non-Fungible Tokens

And finally, you mentioned tokens. If you are refering to Non-fungible Tokens (NFTs), this is a good starting point to learn more:

- https://opensea.io/blog/guides/non-fungible-tokens/